# How to repair the permission of System Python in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, python

- OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3

---

### Cause

In order to make the "YouCompleteMe" plugin works, I tampered with System Python:

1. I renamed the folders `2.7` and `Current` to `2.7-sys` and `Current-sys` respectively in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`
2. Then I soft linked new folders `2.7` and `Current` to the homebrewed Python in `/usr/local/Cellar/Python/`
3. I was told that it is not wise to tamper with files in `/System/` so I deleted the linked folders and renamed the `2.7-sys` and `Current-sys` back to `2.7` and `Current`.

### Issue

When I use Disk Utility to verify disk permissions, it alerted that files in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` should be `lrwxr-xr-x` but they are `-rwxr-xr-x`. I repaired the disk permissions with Disk Utility but when I verified again, the same warnings were raised.

I found an [article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1052220/repairpermissions.html) about the permissions but I do not know which `Receipt` file is related to System Python.

So how should I fix the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is misleading; the permissions are correct ("rwxr-xr-x" = "rwxr-xr-x"), it's the file type that's wrong ("l" != "-"). Specifically, some files that are supposed to be symbolic links (the "l" type) have been replaced with regular files (the "-" lack-of-any-special-type). I'm not sure exactly what happened, but it sounds like you didn't put some things back quite the way they were originally.

Comment: Thank you. I think `rwxr-xr-x` is the correct permission. When I tried to restore the config, I deleted my own `Current` and `2.7`, which were symbolic links, then I renamed `Current-sys` and `2.7-sys` to `Current` and `2.7`. So the system might think that I use a directory to replace a link. I wonder if reinstall the OS X system from the ground and restore by Time Machine will fix the problem.